# Using Azure Redis Caching for ChildAction in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redis, azure-redis-cache, child-actions

I have successfully implemented Azure Redis Cache using the Microsoft RedisOutputCacheProvider which works as expected for general pages.

However, I can't seem to get it to work for child actions, it always use the default OutputCacheProvider.

How can i get it working even for ChildActions?

Comment: This is not an answer - and you might known this already - but here's an exception message which describes what is and isn't allowed for child action caching: `OutputCacheAttribute for child actions only supports Duration, VaryByCustom, and VaryByParam values. Please do not set CacheProfile, Location, NoStore, SqlDependency, VaryByContentEncoding, or VaryByHeader values for child actions.`. In short, I don't think it's even possible to change it from the default provider.